# Filter records with same foreign key and different values in other columns

Tags: mysql, inner-join

My goal is to `SELECT` the `FOREIGN KEY` from all records that exist more than once, having the same foreign key and at least one difference in other 2 specific columns (color, price).

For example i have the following table **items**

```
 fk_id |  color  | price
-------+---------+-------        
   1   |   black |   50  
   1   |   red   |  100  
   1   |   blue  |   75   
   2   |   red   |  100  
   2   |   red   |  100  
   3   |   black |   50 
   3   |   blue  |   75  
   4   |   green |   50
   5   |   blue  |   75
   5   |   blue  |   70
```

The desired result is

```
fk_id 
-----        
  1  
  3
  5
```

Here what i have done so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.fk_id
  FROM items a
  JOIN items b
    ON a.fk_id = b.fk_id
 WHERE a.color <> b.color 
    OR a.price <> b.price
```

Is there any other solution or better way to achieve it?

Comment: You could use < instead of <>

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fk_id
FROM table
GROUP BY fk_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT color) > 1 -- or COUNT(DISTINCT color, price)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

First filter the table to remove all duplicate rows and then use aggregation with the condition `COUNT(*) > 1` in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT fk_id
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM items) t
GROUP BY fk_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/63JmPWqcJPxFZrvyH2gqZT/0).